# Better sharding function for int64 keys in golang?

Tags: algorithm, go, hash

I am using concurrent map from this [repo](https://github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map) where it is possible to select the key type when creating a map using `NewWithCustomShardingFunction`. I just need to provide my own sharding function for `int64` keys and that's what I am using here.

I am also using latest version of `Go` where I can use generics so I decided to use `concurrent-map` with keys as `int64` by implementing my own sharding function.

```
import (
    cmap "github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map/v2"
)

func shardingFunc(key int64) uint32 {
    return uint32(key) // TODO - create a better sharding function that does not rely on how uint32 type conversion works
}

func main() {
    testMap := cmap.NewWithCustomShardingFunction[int64, *definitions.CustomerProduct](shardingFunc)
    // ... use the map ...
}
```

I wanted to know whether my sharding function is okay here for `int64` keys or should I have better sharding function? I don't want to be in situation where it can give me `index out of range` error or any other issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sharding function is a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).  The function should uniformly distribute the keys over a 32 bit space.

If the low four bytes if your init64 values are uniformly distributed, then `uint32(key)` will work as a sharding function.

An example of where `uint32(key)` is a bad choice is where the low bytes have constant values. For example, if the key values are like  0x00010000, 0x00020000, ..., then `uint32(key)` will evaluate to zero. This is not a uniform distribution.

If you don't know how your int64 keys are distributed, then it's best to use all of the key's bits in the shard function.  Here's one that uses XOR:

```
func shardingFunc(key int64) uint32 {
    return uint32(key) ^ uint32(key >> 32) 
}
```

Comment: How will I know whether my low bytes have constant values? I just know I have my int64 as keys and for which I need a sharding function which is better.

Comment: If you don't have any information about the distribution of your int64 key values, then use the xor function described in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For something robust, use crypto/sha256 to hash the key then convert (some of) it to `unint32`:

```golang
func shardingFunc(key int64) uint32 {
    bytes := sha256.Sum256(new(big.Int).SetInt64(key).Bytes())
    return binary.BigEndian.Uint32(bytes[0:32])
}
```

There are more efficient, although more verbose, ways of coding this, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I don't think there's any scenario where a cryptographically strong hash is necessary for sharding. This is drastically more compute- and memory-intensive that it needs to be.

Comment: I agree that it's probably best to use something that mixes better than high ^ low, but as @Adrian notes, there are fast non-cryptographic hashes that mix well, e.g., taking the bottom 32 bits of the Murmur3 finalizer: https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher/blob/master/src/MurmurHash3.cpp#L81

Answer (score 1):

This is a more context sensitive answer, since I know more background information through chat. It may not apply for others.

First, you won't get an "index out of range" because the concurrent map library will always take the remainder after dividing by the number of shards.

Second, integer product IDs are generally sequential, meaning that they will naturally be evenly distributed across each shard.

There are some possible exceptions to this if you happen to have pathologically antagonistic update / access patterns, but realistically it will make no difference. Even in the worst case scenario where only 1 shard is used, the performance will be effectively the same as using a regular Go map, since each shard has it's own regular map internally. If you do find yourself in a situation where performance *really* matters, you would be best to roll your own concurrent map rather than using this library. I know it is billed as a "high-performance solution", but there is no such thing as a 'one-size-fits-all optimization'. It is an oxymoron.